# When I click on radio button the button is clicked but the onclick event doesnt trigger

Tags: html, jquery, winforms

Im using WinForms desktop application for a pseudo screen scrape. We use HtmlDocument to retrieve the html document object.

These html elements are part of the website im trying to scrape.

This is the button im trying to click.

```html
<input class="checkbox" id="PolicyData_IsMailAddress" name="PolicyData.IsMailAddress" onclick="$(this).postAction()" type="radio" value="False">
```

I've tried raising the "onclick" event, clicking it using the id and setting the checked attribute to "checked".

This is what the element looks like after I click it.

```html
<input checked="checked" class="checkbox" id="PolicyData_IsMailAddress" name="PolicyData.IsMailAddress" onclick="$(this).postAction()" type="radio" value="False">
```

The button is selected on the UI and the attribute checked=checked , but the onclick event never triggers.

Comment: You can't call your method on a jquery object. You have to call `postAction()` on click then get your input via `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onclick` event in a `script` tag or JS file like so:

```
<script>
    $('#PolicyData_IsMailAddress').on("click", postAction);
</script>
```

Your button would then look like this:

```
<input class="checkbox" id="PolicyData_IsMailAddress" name="PolicyData.IsMailAddress" type="radio" value="False">
```